# Extract road network data from google map

Tags: google-maps, dataset

I am working on graph project and for the same I need some real life road network data.
Is it possible to extract a road network data of a particular city in a graph format(vetices and edges).

I am interested in a data which can describe exactly each road segment of a city with edge and each road intersection with node....

Any help..?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That sounds like it would be against the [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos).  You probably should look at [openstreetmaps.org](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) (but IANAL)

Comment: @geocodezip: Then the next question is how to extract data from openstreetmaps.org in the format <Source,Destination,Distance> of a selected city.

Answer (score 0):

following is quote of https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/44680/45061

> No, Google's road data is proprietary and is not distributed in a GIS capable format. This is because Google spends a lot of money keeping their GIS accurate and current, and distributing it for free would allow Google's competitors (e.g. Microsoft, MapQuest, Apple, ESRI) to download it. This would forfeit Google's competitive advantage in the web mapping world.
>
> OpenStreetMap does offer downloads of their entire road dataset. The ["Downloading data" Wiki page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data) has some more information. The data download page is [here](http://planet.openstreetmap.org/). If you only need data for a single region or country, I recommend using the prepackaged downloads from [geofabrik.de](http://download.geofabrik.de/openstreetmap/).